# Battery threshold gets overwritten at times

Tags: configuration, laptop, thinkpad, battery

#### Problem

I've encountered an issue with my laptop, where the **battery threshold** settings seem to **get overridden** at times. **Despite not altering the configuration files**, the laptop charges up to 100% instead of respecting the set threshold. Has anyone else experienced this problem or found a solution?

I don't know what information to display, so feel free to edit/comment the post.

#### Information

Thinkpad T480, 5.15.142-1-MANJARO, i3wm, **no DE, no TLP**;

Batteries:

- BAT1 - 72Wh external
- BAT0 - 24Wh internal

##### Output of the threshold files:

```
# First config file
[i3hunor@HunorT480 ~]$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold
90
[i3hunor@HunorT480 ~]$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_end_threshold
90

# Second config file
[i3hunor@HunorT480 ~]$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_stop_threshold
90
[i3hunor@HunorT480 ~]$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_stop_threshold
90
```

##### Pic from the incident

[image: Battery charges]

In this case the external battery charged up to 100%, but (as mentioned) the threshold file says stop at 90%.